# tcl: how to print UTF-8 text to stdout on Windows

Tags: windows, utf-8, tcl, stdout

my little cross-platform Tcl/Tk pet-project uses utf-8 as the text encoding everywhere.

```
encoding system utf-8
fconfigure stderr -encoding utf-8
fconfigure stdout -encoding utf-8

#puts "汉语"
puts "foo"
```

This works great on Linux and macOS, where the standard encoding is UTf-8:

```sh
$ tclsh utf8test.tcl
foo
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all on Windows, where the terminal typically uses `cp1252`, and it consequently outputs garbage:

```sh
$ wine tclsh85.exe utf8test.tcl
潦൯
```

As far as I understand, this is because we cannot really change the encoding of the Windows terminal, and - according to this [sf issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/tcl/bugs/5236/) - I need to detect myself whether the output is going to a terminal or somewhere else.

I have no idea how to make this decision.

So how can I output printable characters to the console in a project that otherwise uses UTF-8 everywhere?

#### edit1

my original example would output some high-unicode points (chinese characters `汉语`).
however, the problem also persists if I try to output a single ASCII string (`foo`).
since most of the text i'm outputting is ASCII anyhow, I would like at least to fix the output for *that*.

i thought that cp1252 would be backwards compatible with ASCII...

Comment: You hit a usual problem, and it is not about tcl, but about terminal (as you already identified). So you must find a way to change the terminal settings (either a different terminal (e.g. linux compatible) or powershell. If your terminal use standard windows encoding, you have just 256 characters, so not much workaround

Comment: this is of course true, and probably my snippet was trying to do too much. my problem is that i can't even output ASCII strings if I set the encoding to `utf-8`. I've updated the question.

Comment: `cp1252` *is* ASCII-compatible, so you have another issue if ASCII strings aren't working either.  You could try changing the terminal to UTF-8 (`chcp 65001`).  Also Windows 10 has beta support for using UTF-8.  Go to Administrative Language Settings and change the system locale.

Answer (score 0):

Output to the real console on Windows is special — it has it's own channel implementation — since the low-level API takes Unicode (I think it is actually UTF-16, but that isn't important here) and Tcl uses the low-level IO API on Windows where it can. I do not know whether Tcl has automatically detected your console correctly. I know absolutely nothing about what interaction there is between the API and Wine's implementation of it and whatever is going on in the host environment.

Console output is *supposed* to Just Work™ if you don't modify the encoding on its channel. Indeed, the usual rule is *don't change encodings except on files and sockets* (where you know the encoding might be not the system one).

Comment: You almost _never_ should alter `encoding system`; among other things, that's the encoding used for filenames (except we use `CreateFileW` all the time on Windows, precisely to avoid just how often the OEM encoding is totally broken).